# Create button from c# to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a table for my project that represent the data from the database and everything is ok but it doesn't create the button in the last column and I have no idea why - can anyone help here?

I'm using asp.net 2010

```
public string getWhileLoopData()
{
    string htmlStr = "";
    Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = (Dictionary<string, string>)Session["CurrentUser"];
    string ArmyName = dic2["UserName"].ToString();
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", ArmyName);
    cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmdd.CommandText = "SELECT CityNum FROM [Users] where ArmyName=@zip";
    int citynum = Convert.ToInt32(cmdd.ExecuteScalar());

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  CityRank, ArmyName, GuildName, Gold, Soliders FROM Users WHERE (CityNum = @num) ORDER BY CityRank", sqlConnection1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", citynum);
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 1;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int CityRank = reader.GetInt32(0);
        string Name = reader.GetString(1);
        string guild = reader.GetString(2);
        int gold = reader.GetInt32(3);
        int soliders = reader.GetInt32(4);

        htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + CityRank + "</td><td>" + Name + "</td><td>" + guild + "</td><td>" + gold + "</td><td>" + soliders + "</td><td><asp:Button ID='" + Name + "' runat='server' Text='Attack' OnClick='AttClick_Clicks' /></td></tr>";
        count++;
    }
    sqlConnection1.Close();
    return htmlStr;
}
```

Comment: you are using server side code in your generated html. If you insert this Piece of code too late in the page life cycle it will not be interpreted by the asp.net engine and will be sent to the Client just as you generate it. Browsers are not able to understand those server side tags.

Comment: then what do i do ? @MarcoLaser

Comment: assuming you are using WebForms. you could use the init-Event of your page to add the html elements to the control collection of your page. You should do that before the load because in case of a postback you won't receive the click-Event of your generated Buttons.

Comment: instead use a gridview or datalist

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing that use the ASP.NET `Table` control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Table table = this.GetTable();
            form1.Controls.Add(table);
        }

        private Table GetTable()
        {
            var table = new Table();

            var u1 = new User { CityRank = "1", Name = "Johannesburg", guild = "1", gold = "1", soliders = "1" };
            var u2 = new User { CityRank = "1", Name = "Cape Town", guild = "1", gold = "1", soliders = "2" };
            var u3 = new User { CityRank = "1", Name = "Kiev", guild = "1", gold = "1", soliders = "3" };

            var users = new List<User> { u1, u2, u3 };

            foreach (User u in users)
            {
                var row = new TableRow();
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.CityRank });
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.Name });
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.guild });
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.gold });
                row.Cells.Add(new TableCell() { Text = u.soliders });

                var button = new Button()
                {
                    ID = u.Name,
                    Text = "Attack"
                };

                button.Command += AttClick_Clicks;
                button.CommandArgument = u.Name;

                var buttonCell = new TableCell();
                buttonCell.Controls.Add(button);

                row.Cells.Add(buttonCell);

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return table;
        }

        protected void AttClick_Clicks(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = e.CommandArgument as String;
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string CityRank { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string guild { get; set; }
        public string gold { get; set; }
        public string soliders { get; set; }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image: Dynamically create ASP.NET table with buttons]

Comment: ok it added it to the website but i need to add it to a tabel how do i do it?

Comment: That's what my code does.It adds all your data to a table plus a button and adds the table to the page.You said button wasn't showing,I gave you a solution.What else?